# Create a dictionary where key would be the header_name from excel sheet using openpyxl

Tags: python, excel, dictionary, openpyxl

```
from openpyxl import *
Variable_Model_Path=defaultdict(list)
Sheet_Name=wb.get_sheet_by_name(Sheet)
for row in Sheet_Name.iter_rows():
    Row=[cell.value for cell in row]
    for cell_ind,cell in enumerate(Row):
        print cell
```

Above is my sample code.

I have an excel sheet which have headers var1, var2 ,var3. I want to create a dictionary {Var1:1,4,7,10} Where Var1 would be header name and the values would be corresponding column values. I am using openpyxl module.Here variable names and values would be given by the user and they will be dynamic.

**Var1 Var2 Var3**

- 1     2     3
- 4     5     6
- 7     8     9
- 10    11    12

Comment: I have issue understanding what is your question ?

Comment: I want to represent header's as key and the corresponding column values as values  to form a dictionary.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This :

```
from openpyxl    import *
from collections import defaultdict
path  = "/Users/romain/Desktop/Classeur2.xlsx"
Sheet = "Feuil1"
wb    = load_workbook(path)

Variable_Model_Path = defaultdict(list)
Sheet_Name          = wb.get_sheet_by_name(Sheet)
keys                = False

for row in Sheet_Name.iter_rows():
    if not keys:
        keys = [cell.value for cell in row]
        continue
    Row=[cell.value for cell in row]
    for cell_ind,cell in enumerate(Row):
        Variable_Model_Path[keys[cell_ind]].append( cell)
```

gives me :

```
Variable_Model_Path
defaultdict(list,
            {u'var 1': [1L, 4L, 7L],
             u'var 2': [2L, 5L, 8L],
             u'var 3': [3L, 6L, 9L]})
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer,this is exactly what I want, but how do i get them in order? I  mean when I have executed this code for my excel sheet ,columns are not ordered, I mean first column appears at the last, middle column appears first in the dictionary.What is the role of        if not keys:
        keys = [cell.value for cell in row]
        continue   in the above code?